# Uploading music through parse return "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

public var AudioPlayer = AVPlayer()
public var SelectedSongNumber = Int()

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{

    var iDArray = [String]()
    var NameArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var ObjectIDQuery = PFQuery (className: "Songs")
        ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
           (objectsArray: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
           var objectIDs = objectsArray as! [PFObject]
           NSLog("\(objectIDs)")
           for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
               self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectID") as! String)
               self.NameArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("SongName") as! String)
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
       })

    }

    func grabSong(){
         var SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
         SongQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block:  {
         (object : PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
                   if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("SongFile")?.url{

                   AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
                   AudioPlayer.play()
           }
        })
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return iDArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = NameArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        SelectedSongNumber = indexPath.row
        grabSong()
    }
}
```

Comment: I got Error on ( for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{ )

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the code. It's probably is the above mentioned code but you need to learn how to debug problems like this by stepping through the code and checking all the values. When you do this the problem should become clear.

Comment: i already solve the problem, it should be (  0...objectIds.count-1{ )